# How to handle public abstract boolean response

Tags: java, android, boolean, response, handle

Like lots of askers on SO, I'm relatively new to java and have attempted to teach myself android programming with some decent success.  I'm sure this is trivial to someone with actual knowledge on the subject.  I'm working on a app that attempts to fetch data from the net and 'returns true' if you get the data and 'returns false' if it doesn't.  I want to do something when it returns false but can't figure out how to properly handle the response.  Right now, I just ignore the response an do nothing.  Any help?

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Someclass.getinfo().maybeShowInfo(this);
        finish();
    }
```

What I would like to do is something like (in pseudo code)

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Someclass.getinfo().maybeShowInfo(this);
        // if false is returned
            // do something
            // else
            // finish();
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "properly handle the response"--are you having a syntax issue (like `boolean response = foo.maybeShowInfo(this); if (!response) { ... }`) or an Android issue (like "what should I do when something goes wrong")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you've combined two things that must be separate.  Make fetching the data and displaying two methods, by two classes.

```
private InfoDao infoDao; // This is a class that gets the data; it's a member of the class with the onBackPressed() method

public void onBackPressed() {
    Info info = this.infoDao.find();
    if (info != null) {
        displayInfo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    boolean result = Someclass.getinfo().maybeShowInfo(this);
    if (result) {
        finish();
    } else {
//      do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBackPressed()   
{
    boolean result = Someclass.getinfo().maybeShowInfo(this);
    if (result = false) 
    {
        //do work for false response;
    } 
    else 
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

don't forget that you have to make your Someclass.getinfo() return true if it succeded and false if it didn't.

Comment: This also was perfect, but I can only mark one correct. Thanks